# Filter SQL Server records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `table1` in SQL Server 2008

It has the following data:

```
id    refId    Date          IsActive
=====================================
1     2        2014-03-01           1
2     2        2014-03-01           1
3     2        2014-04-15           0 <
4     2        2014-04-15           0 <
5     2        2014-05-20           1
6     2        2014-05-20           1
7     4        2014-03-01           1
8     4        2014-03-01           1
9     4        2014-04-15           1 <
10    4        2014-05-20           1
```

**EDIT**

`refId` refers to a person in another table. So I want the persons whose records does not have `Date = 2014-04-15` OR They have `Date = 2014-04-15` but the `IsActive = 0`

So according to the top, the output should be:

```
refId
=====
2
```

I can do this via `MySQL` using this query (**EDIT 2**):

```
SELECT refId 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY refId 
/*Check if there is no value with this date*/
HAVING MAX(Date='2014-04-15') = 0 
/*Check if the date exists but the IsActive flag is off*/
OR MAX(Date='2014-04-15' AND IsActive=0) = 1
```

but the problem is, SQL Server does not accept condition in the `MAX()` function.

Comment: Can you enter sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to only include the refIds that meet your requirements, then this should work

```
select refId
from table1 as t
group by refId
having exists(
  select refId 
  from table1 as t2 
  where [Date]<>'2014-04-15' 
    or ([Date]='2014-04-15' and IsActive=0) 
  group by refId 
  having t.refId=t2.refId 
-- this next line is where we make sure we are only matching 
-- where the total number of records of refId is equal to the total match count
    and count(t.refId)=count(t2.refId)     )
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the query in MySQL:

```
SELECT refId 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY refId 
HAVING MAX(Date='2014-04-15') = 0 OR
       MAX(Date='2014-04-15' AND IsActive=0) = 1;
```

You can readily translate this to SQL Server/ANSI SQL syntax by using the `case` statement:

```
SELECT refId 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY refId 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2014-04-15' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 OR
       MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2014-04-15' AND IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

This query will also work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT refId 
FROM table1 


WHERE (Date!='2014-04-15') 

OR (Date='2014-04-15' AND IsActive=0)
```

Output:

```
        refId
        =====
        2
```